# How do i dynamically allocate memory to a 2D array in C avoiding the stack overflow issue?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, dynamic, stack-overflow

```
pascal = (int **) malloc(no_of_rows * sizeof(int));

for (i = 0; i < no_of_rows; i++)
{
    *(pascal + i) = (int*) malloc(col * sizeof(int));
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong in this code as I am beginner to this language. I keep on getting problem of Stack Overflow? What could be its possible reasons and how could it be avoided?

Comment: Please use some whitespace. Do you hate your readers so much?

Comment: Remove the casts and also change `malloc(no_of_rows * sizeof(int));` to `malloc(no_of_rows * sizeof(int*));`. Also, check the return value of those `malloc`s

Comment: To avoid errors such as `sizeof(int)` instead of `sizeof(int*)`and keep your code easy to change, you should write `p = malloc(number_of_things * sizeof(*p));`

Comment: Please pick one of the two different languages: C **or** C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
pascal=(int **)malloc(no_of_rows * sizeof(int));
```

should be

```
pascal=malloc(no_of_rows * sizeof(int*));
```

Notice the additional `*` I added. In general, you can write it better:

```
pascal=malloc(no_of_rows * sizeof *pascal);
```

Note that casting `malloc`s results is [unnecessary](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html) in C.

Comment: I actually tend to strongly discourage casting `void *` (in C).

Comment: Nice one. :-) However, I thought of adding an elaboration as an answer, can you review it once?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I don't see any problem. Your answer is quite good :)

Answer (score 2):

You already got the right [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30935347/2173917) from Mr. [Blue Moon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1275169/blue-moon). However, to clarify about the error in your case, I want to add an elaboration.

For the code

```
pascal = (int **) malloc(no_of_rows * sizeof(int));
```

it looks like, your `pascal` is of type `int **`, that is, pointer to a pointer-to-`int`.

So, while allocating a valid memory to `pascal`, you need to allocate the size equal to the element it *points to*, and it points to another `integer pointer`.

So, your allocation statement should be

```
pascal=malloc(no_of_rows * sizeof(int*));
```

*Point to notice:*

1. [See why not to cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.
2. The allocation size is calculated as `sizeof(int *)` (size of a pointer to `int`) instead of `sizeof(int)`.

Now, to make this statement more robust, we can (*should*) re-write it as

```
pascal=malloc(no_of_rows * sizeof*pascal);
```

Here, once again, two things to notice,

1. `sizeof` is an operator, it does not need the parenthesise around its operand unless it is a type name.
2. This statement, is independent of the type of `pascal`. even if you change the type of `pascal`, you don't need to change the above statement.

That said, always check for the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer.

Hope this helps.